# Downloading data online from a database

Tags: database

I really hope you will be able to help me !

I am trying to download the data that is available here :

https://www.dubailand.gov.ae/English/services/Eservices/Pages/ServiceCharges.aspx

The website only allows to go from on data to the other by selecting but it just would take hours to go through all of them.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

You need a web scraping tool.  Try pyscrap (https://pypi.org/project/pyscrap/)